# MVC @RenderPage not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC. In the layout page I want to store footer in a file and call it using **RenderPage**. It looks that everything is OK but when I run the website I get this error:

[image: error while calling @RenderPage]

this is the file tree for project
**_Footer.cshtml** is located in **Shared** Folder

[image]

content for **_Footer.cshtml**

```
<div id="copyrights">

<div class="container clearfix">

    <div class="col_half">

    </div>

</div>

</div><!-- #copyrights end -->
```

Comment: Try to change `@RenderPage()` for `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: Right click on page, and in properties. see build action, and compare the same with other pages.

Comment: Check the path of Footer.cshtml. try this @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC you can use 
`@Html.Partial("_Footer")` or `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Footer");}`

Comment: Html.RenderPartial("_Footer") is not working but Html.Partial("_Footer") works!

Comment: @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Footer");}

Comment: @chsword is `@RenderPage` not working/ not available anymore?

Comment: RenderPage only work in WebPages ,  but WebPages TemplateEngine for ASP.NET MVC